# Combining Math and Reading Test Scores presented in standard deviation units from the mean (mean not given)

Tags: statistics, regression, economics, standard-deviation

I am working with a large dataset for regression purposes and am attempting to predict test scores using various societal / demographic factors. There are two scores, math and reading, that I am trying to combine into one. However, I am not sure how to go about this.

Ideally, I would like to create a sort of "composite score" for each county in the dataset based on a combination of its average reading and math scores in standard deviation units from the mean.

For instance, Jefferson County has a reading score of -0.31122487 std. dev. units from the mean and a math score of -0.43663327 std. dev. units from the mean. What would be the most reasonable way to attain a composite score (also in std. dev. units from the mean) so to speak from which to run my regression? I would be applying this formula throughout the dataset. These scores in std. dev. units are the only datapoints provided relating to test scores.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to recover $C = M + V$ (or the [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) of $C$), given the z-score for $M$ and the z-score for $V$. Here, $C$, $M$, and $V$ stand for "combined", "math", and "verbal", respectively. This is not possible without knowing the means and standard deviations of the $M$ and $V$ variables.

The only reasonable thing you could do in the absence of the mean/standard-deviation information is to make the certainly-incorrect assumption that $M$ and $V$ have equal standard deviations, in which case adding their z-scores gives you a z-score for $C$.